# using usereducer with useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to use **useReducer** instead of **useState** for data that is updated using **useEffect** in the codes below because this causes too much rerenders when they are used in a condition to update itself

```
const [complete, setComplete] = useState("");
const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState("");
const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
const [displayPicture, setDisplayPicture] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  if (user.uid) {
    const onChildAdd = database()
      .ref("/User/" + user.uid)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        setComplete(snapshot.val().Complete);
        setUserProfile(snapshot.val().User);
        setDisplayName(snapshot.val().displayName);
        setDisplayPicture(snapshot.val().photoURL);
        // ...
      });

    return () =>
      database()
        .ref("/User/" + user.uid)
        .off("value", onChildAdd);
  }
}, []);
```

below is a condition I am trying to use

```
function CheckInfo() {
  if (!complete) {
    setComplete("complete");
  } else if (!displayName) {
    setDisplayName("myName");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should add a question. Your intention to use reducer instead of multiple atomic states is good, but it's impossible to tell what you want to ask.

Comment: My question is, how can I use useReducer to do what useState is already doing in the code above

Comment: You've got to give it an attempt on your own.  Otherwise you are just asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: oh, okay, i've been watching videos on it, and ive been able to understand it, thanks for your help, you can delete this question. i thought there was an easy way around